# live() and on() methods are not equivalent?

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM element added with .append() and something like:

```
myObject.live({
     mouseenter: function() { // do something
```

and this works fine, but as jQUery 1.7 suggests, I've changed it with on(). But with on() the same function doesn't work. Should I go with live() or there's something I'm missing with on() to make it work with new DOM nodes?

As the jQuery docs states, those functions are quite similar:

live();

```
$("p").live({
click: function() {
$(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
},
 mouseover: function() {
 $(this).addClass("over");
  },
    mouseout: function() {
     $(this).removeClass("over");
   }
});
```

on();

```
$("div.test").on({
 click: function(){
$(this).toggleClass("active");
  },
 mouseenter: function(){
$(this).addClass("inside");
 },
 mouseleave: function(){
  $(this).removeClass("inside");
 }
});
```

the latter will not work with a new node added with .append(); is this right?

Comment: Have you replaced live() with on() or checked the on() specification on the usage and made it appropriate?

Comment: actually I've started with on(), but after seeing it not working as expected I've tried live(), this is why I'm here.

Comment: i do not believe they are equivalent - see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffz2012/eEzwd/1/

Comment: @Jeffz they are not, but i've learned hot to handle it: http://jsfiddle.net/uw2bE/1/

Comment: you are right of course, but I thought people should be aware that they are not aliases of the same thing - in addition both fiddles present them with a good tool to see difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', myObject, function() {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check it out http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/